# I believe Eureka generates private/internal ip addresses for registered instances that are aws services

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, netflix-eureka

I have Eureka running on an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance. My Eureka instance currently has 2 completely separate springboot microservices running on their own beanstalk instances registered with it. Eureka gave these 2 registered instances private/internal ip addresses, and I'm wondering how to access the endpoints in the 2 registered microservices. I believe Eureka notices that they are on amazon's servers and are making them private/internal. I can run the same 2 springboot applications locally in Eclipse pointed to my AWS instance of Eureka and my Beanstalk instance of Eureka will register my local apps with public IP addresses allowing me to consume the endpoints in both of the apps. I would like to access the two beanstalk instances in the same manner. Something tells me that I should set a property in the application.properties or something. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Here are some examples:

This registered instance doesn't work
http://private-aws-ip-address.us-east-1.compute.internal:8080/customers/customerInfo

This registered instance works
http://dougs-machine.attlocal.net:8080/customers/customerInfo

Comment: Did you ever found the solution for this?, I am facing the same problem, I am creating Elastic Beanstalk, EC2 and ECS, with all of those my Eureka Server Registry always get the private IP address and when I try to communicate micro services the can't reach each other because the Ribbon Load Balancer can't reach the IPs

Answer (score 0):

Eureka works as services discovery, clients must use a service discovery mechanism to locate service instances.
You can use client-side (or server-side) discovery pattern.

- **Client-side discovery pattern**, the client is responsible for determining the network locations of available service instances and load balancing requests across them. The client queries a service registry, which is a database of available service instances. The client then uses a load-balancing algorithm to select one of the available service instances and makes a request.A client makes requests (HTTP or TCP) via the ELB using its DNS name. The ELB load balances the traffic among a set of registered Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) instances or EC2 Container Service (ECS) containers. There isn’t a separately visible service registry. Instead, EC2 instances and ECS containers are registered with the ELB itself.
  HTTP servers and load balancers such as NGINX Plus and NGINX can also be used as a server-side discovery load balancer
- **The Server-Side Discovery Pattern**, the client makes a request to a service via a load balancer. The load balancer queries the service registry and routes each request to an available service instance.
  As with client- side discovery, service instances are registered and deregistered with the service registry
  The AWS Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) is an example of a server-side discovery router. ELB is commonly used to load balance external traffic from the Internet. However, you can also use ELB to load balance traffic that is internal to a virtual private cloud (VPC).